# Is it possible to integrate JIRA with mercurial (without fisheye)?

Tags: mercurial, jira

I'm setting up a development server with JIRA as issue tracker and mercurial as SCM.

Is it possible to relate commits with the JIRA's issues (without using fisheye or any commercial tool)?

Comment: It seems that there is a plugin called JHG, but it is a bit outdated (supports up to JIRA 4.1, while I'm using 4.3)

Comment: I found out that bitbucket is supported (both git and mercurial repos). Even if it's silly, I'm going to mirror my repository in bitbucket, allowing my jira to see my code! (bitbucket allows private repos!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the JIRA Mercurial plugin does this, just like the JIRA Subversion plugin does for Subversion. It needs an update for 4.3 though, I must get around to that.