# Howto mirror a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, jira, jira-plugin

in order to bypass the [JIRA-mercurial plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504257/is-it-possible-to-integrate-jira-with-mercurial-without-fisheye), I need to replicate my (private) mercurial repository in a private mercurial repository in bitbucket. I and the other users will continue to "push" our commits to our own private repository, but I want pushed commits to be "forwarded" to a certain bitbucket repository. This way, I can use the JIRA's bitbucket plugin and see the changes related to my bugs.

In other words, I want that, after each push in my private mercurial repository, the commits are forwarded to my repository hosted by bitbucket. I think I should create a push hook, but I never used them before...

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are actually asking. Are you looking for a pre-made commit hook that replicates pushes into another repository? Please clarify what you are looking for or make your actual question more clear.

Comment: sorry... I'm really tired and I exchanged JIRA with mercurial in the first sentence (now it's fixed). The idea is to create a (read-only) mirror in bitbucket of my  private hg repository.

Comment: So, are you just looking for an auto-push functionality from your local Hg repo to a bitbucket-hosted repo?

Comment: yes... so that the two repositories are synchronized

Comment: possible duplicate of [mercurial automatic push on every commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235597/mercurial-automatic-push-on-every-commit)

Comment: I think it is not related to the "automatic push on every commit"... I want to decide when to push my changes to my server, but when my server receives an incoming push, I want it to forward to bitbucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Pls, move it into comment of Matteo answer)*

changegroup isn't correct type of hook for this task,  because

> The changegroup hook is activated once for each push/pull/unbundle,
>   unlike the commit hook, which is run once for each changeset

according to [docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook#The_changegroup_hook), and I suppose, more right way is

```
[hooks]
commit =
```

Comment: No.  changegroup is most certainly the correct hook to use.  You do not need separate pushes for each changeset (commit).  You want to push in bulk, it will be more efficient.  The questions states: I want pushed commits to be "forwarded".  Keyword there is "pushed".

Answer (score 5):

I think that the following hook (installed on my server) solves my problem...

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/path/to/my/repository
```

Answer (score -2):

Depending on what mercurial client you are using, there are a number of different ways to have your local repository "push after commit".

The TortoiseHg windows client allows you to configure this per-repository for all commits (under the "settings->commit" dialog), as well as for individual commits under the "options" menu when committing.

There are also hook scripts that you can use. A quick google search finds many different options.

Comment: I do not want an automatic push. I just want that my changes are automatically forwarded to bitbucket by my server (without TortoiseHg). Before asking the quesiton, I googled for some solution, and I found the hook guide ( http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html ). However, since I never created such hook before, I just want some help...